# What will give me something like ruby readline with a default value?

Tags: ruby, command-line, console, command-line-interface, readline

If I want to have a prompt on the terminal with a default value already typed in, how can I do that?

Ruby's standard `Readline.readline()` lets me set the *history* but not fill in a default value (as far as I can tell, at least)

I would like something like this:

code:

```
input = Readline.readline_with_default('>', 'default_text')
```

console:

```
> default_text|
```

Comment: An example or illustration could make this question more clear.

Comment: it's hard to give an example for interactive console behavior, but here's an attempt.

Comment: do you need the user to be able to modify the default_text, like backspace over it, or do you simply want to read an empty line as the default text?

Comment: yes, I want them to modify it.

Comment: my reading of ext/readline.c leads me to believe it's not supported in Ruby's Readline library. If this functionality is possible in GNU Readline, an extension could be created, otherwise, I second Farrel's ncurses suggestion.

Comment: BTW the latest version of [haskeline](http://trac.haskell.org/haskeline) (0.6.4.0) has such an API: [`getInputLineWithInitial`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskeline/0.6.4.0/doc/html/System-Console-Haskeline.html#g:5): "This function behaves in the exact same manner as `getInputLine`, except that it pre-populates the input area. The text that
resides in the input area is given as a 2-tuple with two Strings. The string on the left of the tuple is what will appear to the left of the cursor and the string on the right is what will
appear to the right of the cursor."

Comment: And I'm in the search of something like this for Curry -- http://stackoverflow.com/q/5737170/94687 . If not the pre-populated input text requirement, a simple readline-based wrapper like `rlwrap` would do for any program... (Perhaps, we could make up a wrapper like `rlwrap`, but with a protocol for pre-population of the input line?..)

Answer (score 10):

What you are asking is possible with `Readline`. There's a callback where you can get control after the prompt is displayed and insert some text into the read buffer.

This worked for me:

```
Readline.pre_input_hook = -> do
  Readline.insert_text "hello.txt"
  Readline.redisplay

  # Remove the hook right away.
  Readline.pre_input_hook = nil
end

input = Readline.readline("Filename: ", false)
puts "-- input:#{input.inspect}"
```

BTW, I fairly tried to use HighLine, but it appeared to be a no-alternative to me. One of the disappointing reasons was the fact that `HighLine#ask` reads cursor movement keys as regular input. I stopped looking in that direction after that sort of discovery.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for showing this great solution. Specially the `Readline.pre_input_hook = nil` trick. I didn't know that pre_input_hook can be used like this. So smart!

Comment: Be warned! This do not work in the Readline implementation on MacOS X. I was trying for an hour to figure out why it wasn't working. There are no errors, no warnings, nothing, just doesn't work. In ubuntu, it works properly.

Comment: Looks like `insert_text` invokes GNU's `rl_insert_text`, which differs between Ubuntu and MacOS. https://apidock.com/ruby/Readline/insert_text/class

Comment: The example in this answer failed to work for me (on current Ubuntu) - no errors and nothing inserted at the prompt. I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 5):

+1 to highline

try with something like:

```
require 'highline/import'
input = ask('> ') {|q| q.default = 'default_text'} # > |default_text|
```

Comment: And what do the vertical bars (in the comment) signify?

Comment: That's the output as you'd see it. If you enter nothing. input is set to 'default_text'.

Comment: @rainkinz: So, the user will have to see the vertical bars, won't he? That's somehow unusual: to input something not just after the prompt, but between two vertical bars.

Comment: It differs from the requirement the original post describes -- the default value should be editable.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a job for ncurses. Seems like rbcurse (http://rbcurse.rubyforge.org/) is the best maintained API at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I'm struggling with the same thing.

The way I'm doing it right now is:

```
options = ["the_text_you_want"]
question = "use TAB or up arrow to show the text > "

Readline.completion_append_character = " "
Readline::HISTORY.push options.first
Readline.completion_proc = proc { |s| options.grep( /^#{Regexp.escape(s)}/ ) }

while value = Readline.readline(question, true)
  exit if value == 'q'
  puts value.chomp.strip #do something with the value here
end
```

yes, it's silly, but it has been the only way I've found to do it.

**did anybody find any solution to this?**

Comment: Yes, there is a solution, look for the `pre_input_hook` one around.

Answer (score 2):

New answer to an old question, but adding because I found this looking for an answer to the same question.

[tty-prompt](https://github.com/piotrmurach/tty-prompt) looks like it does what you are looking for - asking for input with an editable default. It's the only gem I found that would give me the editable default (but there may be others)

Full code to to that would look like:

```
require "tty-prompt"
prompt = TTY::Prompt.new
input = prompt.ask('What is your name?', value: 'Bob')
```

Answer (score 1):

[Highline](http://highline.rubyforge.org/doc/) doesn't do exactly what you describe, but maybe it's close enough.