# Present editable input to a user with ruby

Tags: ruby, bash

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 with Ruby 1.9.3. I'm trying to present an editable input to the user.
The only solution I happened to find was using the read command from the bash-shell:
read -e -i "Default Value" -p "Prompt> " ; echo $REPLY
Executed from the command line it works well, the edited input is in the REPLY variable.
But if I define

```
def edits
  `read -e -i "Default Value" -p "Prompt> ; echo $REPLY" ` 
end
```

and run it in ruby I get an error:

```
sh: 1: read: Illegal option -e
```

My questions are now:

1. What went wrong in my solution?
2. Is there a better solution in ruby?

Comment: Naturally I Used back-ticks around the OS-command in the ruby definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-e` flag for read is a `bash` extension. You're using the `sh` shell (or something emulating `sh`), which has the read command but doesn't have that flag.

The [Readline](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/readline/rdoc/Readline.html) module provides terminal input, with editing, from within Ruby:

```
require "readline"
while buf = Readline.readline("> ", true)
  p buf
end
```

It also has history and completion features.

Comment: My emphasis is not on the prompt, which readline gives, but on the "Default Value" string, that a user can edit. Can readline display such a string to edit?

Comment: If I define  def shell `echo $SHELL` end, I get /bin/bash, so ruby is always calling a bash-shell, in which read -e should run???

Comment: You can insert your default text in Readline's pre input hook (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29743124/182402)).

Comment: The `$SHELL` variable contains your default shell, not the shell that's currently running (see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45459/94707)).

Comment: You're on Ubuntu, which means `/bin/sh` points to `dash`, not `bash`, which is what Ruby will use.

Comment: Thank you Wander,  unfortunately I'm running ruby 1.9.3 which doesn't yet know  Readline's pre input hook...

Comment: Right, hmm. You could call bash from dash (`bash -c`) but it would add a hard dependency on bash. You could also try something like Highline.

Comment: Wander, I followed your suggestion and did  `bash -c "read -e -i 'Default Value' EDITED"; echo $EDITED` Then the input and editing works fine, but the return is always "\n" instead of the string in $EDITED.

Comment: You might need to escape the dollar sign.

Comment: Wonderful, changing $EDITED in \\$EDITED finally did it!